# Automapper mapping list becomes 0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

I'm mapping a list to another list with Automapper, but it seems that my items are not copied.

Here is my code:

```
var roles = userRepo.GetRoles(null).ToList();
Mapper.CreateMap < List<Domain.Role>, List<Role>>();
var mappedRole = Mapper.Map<List<Domain.Role>, List<Role>>(roles); //the count is 0, list empty :(
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

1. No exceptions were thrown.
2. All properties has the same names.

Domain.Role

```
public class Role
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Role

```
public class Role
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I assume you've verified that roles has data?

Comment: @Derek Beattie, yes, `roles.Count` is 2. `mappedRole.Count` became 0.

Comment: Shouldn't matter but stick the assert after the .CreateMap but before the .Map

Comment: @Derek Beattie, nothing happened. The assert didn't throw. I think I should probably loop and have automapper map them 1 by 1.

Comment: Post the two Role types.

Comment: Strange, I use AM to do that all the time...thinking.

Comment: Try using Mapper.CreateMap <Domain.Role, Role>();

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589471/mapping-lists-using-automapper/5589563#5589563

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Don't create maps between lists and array, only between the types:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Domain.Role, Role>();
```

and then:

```
var mappedRole = Mapper.Map<List<Domain.Role>, List<Role>>(roles);
```

[AutoMapper handles lists and arrays](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists%20and%20Arrays&referringTitle=Home) automatically.

Comment: I am experiencing some weird behavior while using the AutoMapper.  For some reason, while mapping between two lists, the first item seems to be repeated n times in the destination list.  I created an article here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268362/automapper-for-a-list-scenario-only-seems-to-repeat-mapping-the-first-object-in asking about this issue.  I think I am using the AutoMapper according to the specs, though I am a newbie to it.  Please review and let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had the (parent) type mapping configured correctly but I didn't add the mappings for the child records, so for this:

```
class FieldGroup
{
    string GroupName { get; set; }
    ...
    List<Field> fields { get; set; }
}
```

I had to add the second mapping:

```
cfg.CreateMap<FieldGroup, FieldGroupDTO>();
cfg.CreateMap<Field, FieldDTO>(); << was missing
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid adding Collections in your mapper configuration. Make sure you add all the types(classes). I had errors when collections were not in the config, but that was because all types were not included. Bit misleading but that's where the problem lies.  Point is, remove all collections from mapper config and add all classes only. Add collections when doing the actual transformation ie. call to mapper.Map.

```
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Infrastructure.Entities.Pet, Domain.Model.Pet>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Infrastructure.Entities.Owner, Domain.Model.Owner>().ReverseMap();
        });

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        var domainPetOwners = mapper.Map<List<Domain.Model.Owner>>(repoPetOwners);
```