# Automapper returning count of 0 from List map?

Tags: c#, automapper

so I have found a few questions on SO (for example: [Automapper mapping list becomes 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590550/automapper-mapping-list-becomes-0)) about automapper returning a list of 0 from a mapping, but none seem quite what I'm looking at.

I have two types:

```
public class DNSContract : BaseContract
{
    public int DoNotSolicitID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Zip4 { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
    public string Partner { get; set; }
    public string Origination { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public DNS_Entity()
    {
        // set default values which can be expicity set if needed
        InsertDT = DateTime.Now;
        InsertDT = DateTime.Now;
       // InsertUserID = 999;
        Origination = "RDI";
    }

    public long DoNotSolicitID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Zip4 { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
    public string Partner { get; set; }
    public string Origination { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> InsertDT { get; set; }
    //public int InsertUserID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdateDT { get; set; }
    //public int UpdateUserID { get; set; }
}
```

pretty easy there.  Here's a "quick map" method I'm using:

```
 public static TToType QuickMap<TFromType, TToType>(this TFromType fromObject, TToType toObject)
        where TFromType : class
        where TToType : class, new()
    {
        // Look for an existing map, and if none is found add one.
        if (Mapper.FindTypeMapFor(typeof (TFromType), typeof (TToType)) == null)
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap(typeof (TFromType), typeof (TToType));
        }

        // Execute the auto map
        TToType map = Mapper.Map(fromObject, toObject);

        return map;
    }
```

so far so good I guess. However,

```
TToType map = Mapper.Map(fromObject, toObject);
```

does nothing. The problem is that this code returns an empty DNSContract when it should return 4 (from my unit test):

```
 using (var scope = dnsWork)
        {
            scope.Register(this);

            var one = WhereInternal(whereClause);
            var two = one.ToList();
            var three = two.QuickMap(new List<DNSContract>());
            return three;
            //return WhereInternal(whereClause).ToList().QuickMap(new List<DNSContract>());
        }
```

I've broken the call out into one, two, three for sanity's sake while debugging this.  So basically, I have a List and want to return a List and that's failing.

Something that does work is:

```
return Mapper.Map(two, new List<DNSContract>());
```

but I'd like to use the generic method and not have mapping sprinkled throughout the service layers.

With automapper do I need to do anything special for list mappings? I think that's the problem  I've mapping types but for some reason the list to typeB is just not working right.

Thanks. This has been annoying me for a couple of weeks now and sort of ignored it, but I need to fix is ASAP.

**UPDATE #1**: as requested, below is the WhereInternal method in a snippet of its class which is in my DAL and pulls from Entity Framework:

```
 public abstract class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }

    private IDbSet<T> _objectset;

    private IDbSet<T> ObjectSet
    {
        get { return _objectset ?? (_objectset = UnitOfWork.Context.Set<T>()); }
    }

    public IQueryable<T> WhereInternal(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return ObjectSet.Where(expression);
    }
}
```

I don't think it's really important in the context, since I convert to a list and then attempt to map.

Comment: Please submit what does WhereInternal(whereClause) return - i suspect IEnumerable<something>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is a problem in your implementation of QuickMap method - i'm not sure why you want a second argument to be passed at all if you actually just need a **type** of it. You also call not the most straightforward methods to perform the mappings.

Second, as per [documentation](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists%20and%20Arrays), register a mapping only for the **simple types**, hence I would separate registration and mapping itself.
Here is what I came up with:

```
static class MapperHelper
{    
    static void Register<TSource, TDestination>()
    {
        var mapped = Mapper.FindTypeMapFor(typeof(TSource), typeof(TDestination));
        if (mapped == null)
        {
            var expression = Mapper.CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>();
        }
    }
    static TDestination QuickMap<TSource, TDestination>(this TSource source)
    {
         return Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>(source);
    }
}
```

And the usage:

```
//Registration
MapperHelper.Register<DNS_Entity, DNSContract>();
//Mapping
var result = WhereInternal(whereClause).ToList().QuickMap<IList<DNS_Entity>, IList<DNSContract>>();
```