# Map List<User> to List<userReponseDto>

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-identity, automapper

### How do I use automapper to map a list of identity users to a list dto?

I'm having difficulty getting my automapper to map a list of identity users to a dto. I pull the user list with a lengh > 0, but when I map it, it becomes an empty list. Here is my code.

startup.cs

```cs
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
     var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
            {
                mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
            });
     IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
            services.AddSingleton(mapper);
}
```

MappingProfile.cs

```cs
public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            // Add as many of these lines as you need to map your objects

            CreateMap<User, userReponseDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id));
            ;
            CreateMap<List<User>, IEnumerable<userReponseDto>>();
            CreateMap<List<User>, List<userReponseDto>>();
        }
    }
```

userReponseDto.cs

```cs
public class userReponseDto
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? LockoutEnd { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a flag indicating if two factor authentication is enabled for this
        //     user.
        public bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a flag indicating if a user has confirmed their telephone address.
        public bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a telephone number for the user.
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     A random value that must change whenever a user is persisted to the store
        public string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }

        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a flag indicating if a user has confirmed their email address.
        public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }

        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the email address for this user.
        public string Email { get; set; }

        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the user name for this user.
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a flag indicating if the user could be locked out.
        public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the number of failed login attempts for the current user.
        public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
    }
```

User.cs

```cs
public class User : IdentityUser
    {
    }
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```cs
        public DbSet<User> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
```

UsersController.cs

```cs
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase{
            private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

            private readonly IMapper _mapper;
            public UsersController(IMapper mapper,ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _mapper = mapper;
            _context = context;
        }

 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult GetUsers()
        {

                    // return Ok(_context.ApplicationUsers.ToList());
                    var list = _context.ApplicationUsers.ToList();
                    IEnumerable<userReponseDto> userList ;
                    var response = _mapper.Map<List<userReponseDto>>(list);
                    // var response =
                    userList= list.Select(_mapper.Map<IdentityUser, userReponseDto>);

                    return Ok(userList);

        }

}
```

Comment: You don't need to configure `List<User>`, it already understands `List<T>`.

Comment: I think declaring the map for the list is what called it to fail to map.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to determine that you shouldn't define maps per lists as per [Automapper mapping list becomes 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590550/automapper-mapping-list-becomes-0?noredirect=1&lq=1) @darin-dimitrov. I thought this was due to nested attributes in the identity user. So my mapping profile becomes.

```cs
        CreateMap<User, userReponseDto>()
           .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id));
        CreateMap<IdentityUser, userReponseDto>()
           .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id));
```

With no list maps declared. Then

```cs
var list = _context.ApplicationUsers.ToList();
var response = _mapper.Map<List<userReponseDto>>(list);
```

now works properly.

Comment: If the property name and the type are the same in both the entity and the Dto, you do not need to explicitly map. It's picked up by default.