# Automapper Object with inside list of object to primitive mapping

Tags: automapper

I'm trying to create map for automapper to let me map those entity

Entities

```
public class Entity 
{
    ...
    public List<NavigationEntity> Navs { get; set; }
}

public class NavigationEntity   
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

DTO that need to be create with entities

```
public class EntityDto 
{
    ...
    public List<int> NavIds { get; set; }
}
```

This doesnt seem's to do the job! What could do the job ?

```
CreateMap<Entity, EntityDto>().ReverseMap();
CreateMap<NavigationEntity, int>().ConstructUsing(x => x.Id);
```

EDIT

Tried to add
CreateMap< List < SystemsTags >, List< int >>();

but still it doesnt map

Comment: It could be helpful for you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589471/mapping-lists-using-automapper

Comment: doesn't help me i think, i will edit to show diff

Comment: The full error message should tell you what the problem is.

Comment: there is no error message, it simply doesnt map the NavigationEntity

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should rename `public List<NavigationEntity> Navs { get; set; }` and `public List<int> NavIds { get; set; }` to the same name. If it is still not working try to also change ConstructUsing to ConvertUsing. And if you need the reverseMap of Entity to EntityDTO you should also add

```
CreateMap<int, NavigationEntity>().ConvertUsing(x => new NavigationEntity { Id = x });
```

final code

```
public class Entity 
{
    ...
    public List<NavigationEntity> Navs { get; set; }
}

public class NavigationEntity   
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class EntityDto 
{
    ...
    public List<int> Navs { get; set; }
}

...
CreateMap<Entity, EntityDto>().ReverseMap();
CreateMap<NavigationEntity, int>().ConvertUsing(x => x.Id);
CreateMap<int, NavigationEntity>().ConvertUsing(x => new NavigationEntity { Id = x });
```