# use automapper to map models instead of foreach statement

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id {get;set;}        
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Owner OwnerData {get;set}
}

public class Owner
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Phone {get;set;}
    public string CarName {get;set;}
}      

Owner ownerData = repository.Get<Owner>(id);
IEnumerable<Car> cars = repository.Get<Car>();
```

// map all objects in the collection cars and set OwnerData

```
    var data = new List<Car>();
    foreach(var car in cars) //replace this with automapper
    {
       car.OwnerData = new Owner
       {
          CarName = ownerData.CarName,
          Name = ownerData.Name,
          Phone = ownerData.Phone
       };

       data.Add(car);
    }
```

How can I take advantage of automapper and replace whole foreach with automapper (iterate through whole cars collection and set Owner data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping Lists using Automapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589471/mapping-lists-using-automapper)

Answer (score -1):

At first, you should add `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection NuGet` package to your project.
After that create a Class called `AutoMapperProfiles` and inherit it from the `Profile`.

```
public class AutoMapperProfiles : Profile
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create mapping configuration from one type to another type
    /// </summary>
    public AutoMapperProfiles()
    {
        Car oCar = new Car();
        CreateMap<oCar.OwnerData, Owner>();
        CreateMap<Owner, oCar.OwnerData>();
    }
}
```

After that configure the AutoMapper on the `Startup.cs` class.

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperProfiles).Assembly);
```

You should inject `IMapper` into your methods. Here I used *constructor injection*

```
private readonly IMapper _mapper;

/// <summary>
/// Inject Generic Repository and IMapper Service to the controller
/// </summary>
/// <param name="mapper"></param>
public YourConstructor(IMapper mapper)
{
    _mapper = mapper;
}
```

Then you can use it like this.

```
Car oCar = new Car();
var data = _mapper.Map<List<oCar.OwnerData>>(cars);
```

**The advantage is using this method is DI (Dependency Injection)**

> Hope this will work.